# Want to make img background a flex-box and overlay three black text boxes with space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create three text boxes with white text and a black background laid on top of a background image, all inline by using display flex.

I was able to accomplish this with a flex previously in my html/css code with images, but now the boxes are appearing below one another.

Please help! Much appreciated!

```
<!--locations-->
    <section>
        <div class="locations">
            <div><img class="img-locations-background" src="C:\Users\vkuzma\OneDrive - Compass Energy Systems Ltd\Desktop\VS Sheet\Tea Cozy\Photos\img-locations-background.jpg"></div>
                    <div id="box-1">
                        <h3>Downtown</h3>
                        <p>384 West 4th St</p>
                        <p>Suite 108</p>
                        <p>Portland, Maine</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="box-2">
                        <h3>East Bayside</h3>
                        <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
                        <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
                        <p>Portland, Maine</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="box-3">
                        <h3>Oakdale</h3>
                        <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
                        <p>Second Floor</p>
                        <p>Portland, Maine</p>
                    </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="loca">Locations</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

```css
/* locations */

.locations {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 500px;
}

.img-locations-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.9;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.loca {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: seashell;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 99%;
    text-align: center;
}

#box-1 {
    color: seashell;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: flex;
    }

#box-2 {
    color: seashell;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: flex;
  }

#box-3 {
    color: seashell;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by placing a z-axis. also in the next lesson i learned about grids. you can also do background-img in CSS rather than HTML.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first of all the **display: flex** property should not be applied on individual elements rather it is to be applied on the parent of the elements you want to position. So, wrap the boxes in a sort of wrapper like this **box-wrapper**:

```html
        <div class="box-wrapper">
          <div id="box-1">
            <h3>Downtown</h3>
            <p>384 West 4th St</p>
            <p>Suite 108</p>
            <p>Portland, Maine</p>
          </div>
          <div id="box-2">
            <h3>East Bayside</h3>
            <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
            <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
            <p>Portland, Maine</p>
          </div>
          <div id="box-3">
            <h3>Oakdale</h3>
            <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
            <p>Second Floor</p>
            <p>Portland, Maine</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

next apply css on this wrapper.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

use **position: absolute** to position the boxes according to your screen. Also you should put your background image through css using the **background-image** property.